# jQuery Content Slider (more of CSS)

Tags: jquery, css

i have a huge (for me at the moment) problem with CSS.
I am using the [Coda-Slider 2.0](http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/) (it's not the best Solution for my originnaly Problem - but more later)
I restyled it the way i needed to: Custom Tabs on the right of the slider, so it looks like a featured Content Slider.
When a tab is active it should be partly in the mainframe of the slider. But it is always behind (i tried using z-index and switsching the position in HTML).
And here the Code for people want to help me :)

HTML Code:

```
<div class="coda-slider-wrapper">

    <div class="coda-slider preload" id="coda-slider-1">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-wrapper">
                <img src="images/cycle-img.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-wrapper">
                <h2 class="title">Panel 2</h2>
                <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
                <div class="tabInfos"><a href="#Link">I am linked to ya</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .coda-slider -->
<div id="coda-nav-1" class="perszlsdNav">
<ul>
    <li class="tab1 first">
    <a href="#1" class="current">
    <div>
        <h4>VfL Mühlbach - TSV Neckarbischofsheim</h4>
        Beim VfB Epfenbach sahen die Zuschauer
        zunächst ein ausgeglichenes Spiel.
    </div>
    </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab2"><a href="#2"><div>
        <h4>VfL Mühlbach - TSV Neckarbischofsheim</h4>
        Beim VfB Epfenbach sahen die Zuschauer
        zunächst ein ausgeglichenes Spiel.
    </div></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div><!-- .coda-slider-wrapper -->
```

CSS-Code

```
    .coda-slider-wrapper { padding: 10px; width: 640px; background: #ccc; }

    .coda-slider {background: #fff;height: 246px;}

    /* Use this to keep the slider content contained in a box even when JavaScript is disabled */
    .coda-slider-no-js .coda-slider { overflow: auto !important; padding-right: 20px }

    /* Change the width of the entire slider (without dynamic arrows) */
    .coda-slider, .coda-slider .panel { width: 368px }


    /* Change margin and width of the slider (with dynamic arrows) */
    .coda-slider-wrapper.arrows .coda-slider, .coda-slider-wrapper.arrows .coda-slider .panel { width: 600px }
    .coda-slider-wrapper.arrows .coda-slider { margin: 0 10px }

    /* Arrow styling */
    .coda-nav-left a, .coda-nav-right a { background: #000; color: #fff; padding: 5px; width: 100px }

    /* Tab nav */
    .coda-nav ul li a.current { background: #39c }

    /* Panel padding */
    .coda-slider .panel-wrapper { padding: 0 }

    .panel {
        height: 246px;
    }

    /* Preloader */
    .coda-slider p.loading { padding: 20px; text-align: center }

/* Don't change anything below here unless you know what you're doing */

    /* Tabbed nav */
    .coda-nav ul { clear: both; display: block; margin: auto; overflow: hidden }
    .coda-nav ul li { display: inline }
    .coda-nav ul li a { background: #000; color: #fff; display: block; float: left; margin-right: 1px; padding: 3px 6px; text-decoration: none }

    /* Miscellaneous */
    .coda-slider-wrapper { clear: both; overflow: auto }
    .coda-slider { float: left; overflow: hidden; position: relative }
    .coda-slider .panel { display: block; float: left }
    .coda-slider .panel-container { position: relative }
    .coda-nav-left, .coda-nav-right { float: left }
    .coda-nav-left a, .coda-nav-right a { display: block; text-align: center; text-decoration: none }

    .perszlsdNav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    div.perszlsdNav {
        float: right;
        z-index: 999999;
    }
    .perszlsdNav ul li {
        margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    }
    .perszlsdNav ul li.first {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .perszlsdNav ul li a {
        display: block;
        width: 262px;
        background: #fff;
        font-size: 10px;
        color: #08097e;
        height: 54px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .perszlsdNav ul li a.current {
        display: block;
        width: 298px;
        margin: 0 0 0 -36px;
        background: #08097e;
        font-size: 10px;
        color: #fff;
        height: 54px;
        text-decoration: none;
        z-index: 9999999999999;
    }
    .perszlsdNav ul li a div {
        padding: 6px;
    }
    .perszlsdNav ul li a div h4 {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 0 0 5px 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

the following: .perszlsdNav ul li a (should be in front of .coda-slider)

i appreciate your help.

Greetings,
me

Comment: I cannot help it, and please do not take offense at this, but I do find it rather amusing and ironic that your CSS code contains this comment in it: "Don't change anything below here unless you know what you're doing."

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like part of the issue is you never set a `position` on the `perszlsdNav`(unless I am missing it elsewhere in the code) so the `z-index` is ignored. You need either a `relative` or `absolute` position set to have `z-index` do anything for you.

```
div.perszlsdNav {         
  float: right;         
  z-index: 999999; 
  position: relative; /* Add this for your z-index */    
}
```

You will probably then be able to eliminate your `z-index` on `.perszlsdNav ul li a.current` (which also did not have any position set).